# How can I get mod_perl running in Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, perl, apache-httpd

I've installed mod_perl, and even tried enabling it, unfortunately it seems to be preventing apache from starting.

```
LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so
```

here's the error.

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 84: 25312 Segmentation fault      $HTTPD -k $ARGV
```

I switched httpd to run httpd.itk instead of worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same problem with i686 Arch.  I just did a `pacman -Syu` this morning, and a `pacman -S extra/mod_perl` right now. I picked up Perl 5.14 with this morning's update.

Looks like some kind of bug: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/25008